# HttpClient timing out requests after being active for sometime

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, servicepointmanager

I am using a **single instance** of System.Net.Http.HttpClient to send requests from a windows service to multiple RESTful API's.

I ran into a strange issue where some of the HTTP requests are timing out at more or less regular intervals. I get lots of timeout somewhere every **45 - 60 minutes**.

Here is the frequency of such timeouts.

[image: Frequency of errors]

Here is how I create a HttpClient,

```
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100;
        _client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler
        {
          UseProxy = false,
          Proxy = null
        });
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

The DefaultConnectinoLimit was increased after some requests timing out. Should this be increased further or is there an optimal value that I can use ?

Is there anything else that could be causing this problem ?

Any thoughts or suggestions on this is hugely appreciated.

**NOTE:** I am running 100 threads and using SendAsync calls on those.

Comment: It could be bottleneck on your rest server.

Comment: There is a number of reasons why this would happen. Most of these are outside of your control i.E. The server may have a maximum time for any given connection. Any router/firewall may have such a mechanism.

Comment: try increasing timeout in ScriptManager if u have one AsyncPostBackTimeout="400"

Comment: @jekcom, first place I looked. I was not able to find this timed out request in the REST API logs at that interval.

Comment: @Frost_Mourne, I already have a timeout associated with the HttpClient set to 30 seconds and its actually timing out at that point. From what I can see this will provide the same functionality, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @MrPaulch, I am facing this problem only when running from a windows service. I have another REST API calling this REST API for similar calls and haven't faced a problem with that at any point. So, I suspect that there is something when running as a windows service that is causing this problem.